# Where to view man pages for Bash builtin commands?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, manpage

For example, when I type `man fg`, or `man history`, the same manpage, `BUILTIN(1)` will be displayed. There is a list of commands, but not the specification of their usage. Where can I find them?

Comment: Perhaps see also the [Bash Reference Manual.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Builtin-Index.html)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`BUILTIN` commands don't have separate man pages. Those are covered by `help` pages. You can do:

```
help history
```

or

```
help fg
```

Comment: Works for bash, but it seems zsh does not have a built-in help.

Comment: `zsh` has extensive, but unconfigured by default, support for accessing help extracted from the man pages. See "Accessing On-line Help" in `man zshcontrib` for details.

Comment: Worth noting is that the `help` entries in the forthcoming 4.3 release seem to have been improved, at least in how they are formatted. Also, they've fixed the bug where `help read` gives you the entires for `read` and `readonly`, due to substring matching.

Comment: @franklsf95: Since you tagged your question as bash that's my answer was centered on that.

Comment: for OS X, partly solved, [What do the numbers in a man page mean? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean); if you try `brew install coreutils`, maybe fix this problem, - [Install and Use GNU Command Line Tools on macOS/OS X - Top Bug Net](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/)

Comment: if you online, use [explain shell in command line](https://gist.github.com/markhuyong/877aeb2dcedc58d0a3d107c1109945b4)

Answer (score 11):

On zsh, the answers above aren't very helpful.

You can look at the shell's own manual with `man zsh`. It will tell you that the manual is too long (hah!) and provide a list of sections with the actual content. From there we learn that `man zshbuiltins` explains built-in commands. It's a huge listing each one and its explanation, you can search with `/`.

Answer (score 10):

I have the following bash function defined in my ~/.bashrc:

```
bashman () 
{ 
    man bash | less -p "^       $1 "
}
```

This allows me to (in most cases) jump directly to the relevant section of the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) man page for the given builtin.  E.g.

```
bashman fg
```

jumps directly to:

```
   fg [jobspec]
          Resume  jobspec  in the foreground, and make it the current job.
          If jobspec is not present, the shell's notion of the current job
          ...
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work quite so well for some builtins - `history` is one of them.  In those cases, you will have to <kbd>n</kbd> through the man page several times to get to the required section.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation for commands that are shell builtins are with the man pages for the shell.

See for example: [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for the history or fg command.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 commands to find more information about shell builtins.

`type <command>` - Tells you what type of a command it is. Fun fact, `type` is a shell builtin as well. Type `type type` and hit enter and see more details.

`help` - Lists some shell builtin commands by default.

`help <command>` - Gives more information about  `<command>`

`info` - This is kind of the man page for shell builtins. Its CLI, of course, but it's hyperlinked. However, it's hard to navigate and it usually takes me around 5 minutes to get a hang of it. Type `info` and read from the first line.