# man page of fc builtin uses − rather than - for options

Tags: syntax-error, language-lawyer, documentation, manpage

I know that [BUILTIN commands don't have separate man pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22992052/5825294), however I am curious about the following.

Upon executing `man fc` in the terminal I searched for `-l` to look for its description. However, there is no result.

The reason is that the `man` page for `fc` (and maybe other builtins?) uses `−` (which corresponds to `<−> 8722, Hex 2212, Oct 21022, Digr -2`) rather than `-` for option (even if the actual way to use them is the latter, not the former).

Is this somehow intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fc` is part of the POSIX Shell & Utilities, which means it is standardized for better portability. Its [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fc.html) page has a description of the utility with all the portable options, all using the standard ASCII hyphen character (`0x2d`).

Also, the [Utility Conventions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) part of POSIX does mention:

> Guideline 4:
>       All options should be preceded by the '-' delimiter character.

In which `-` is the "standard" ASCII hyphen character (0x2D).

So I'd say that the issue with the `−` is purely due to aesthetic reasons (probably to make the hyphens more distinguishable/easier to read).